# Uable to delete large data on parse.com

Tags: shell, parse-platform

I am facing a problem in deleting large data from parse.com

Firstly i filtered the data using filter but it displays me only at max 100 rows and then i have to select this 100 rows and delete , and then again select and delete next 100.

Is there any way i can delete all data matching the filter,
something like

```
        DELETE FROM Tablename WHERE fieldname LIKE '%foo%'
```

or is it possible to execute query in parse.com

or is there a way to deleted it using shell script and parse somehow (any package might help me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this programmatically, you can create a query to get all the objects and then delete them. Here is an example using swift for iOS:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: TABLENAME)
query.whereKey(fieldname, equals: "%foo%")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(
     {(objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            for object in objects {
                 object.deleteInBackground()
             }
     })
```

The documentation for parse in any of its supported languages can be found here: https://parse.com/docs/

Comment: is it possible to do the same thing using shell script in bash

Comment: @Moses not possible using Parse's available libraries. You can see their 3rd party and native libraries here: https://parse.com/docs/api_libraries